# How to pass url in axios.get(apiendpoint)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, axios

How to pass the apiurl in axios.get()?

I am getting data from asp.net model displayed in html page.

My sql table comprise of title= "first title" , and apiurl = "/api/abc".

If I specify with static data it works. Example:

```
axios.get('/api/abc')
```

and then all chartjs code will display my chart perfectly.

My View has got data from model. code as follows:

```
@foreach (var a in model)
{
<myvuecomponent title = "@a.title" apiurl = "@a.apiurl"><myvuecomponent>
}
```

How do I pass data dynamically in javascript file?

My component is displaying correct title. But I need help on passing the apiurl in --> axios.get(apiurl)

I am getting 404 axios error.

Comment: It would seem like an answer cannot be concrete because we have no idea where the execution of `axios.get` occurs. Can you provide that?

Comment: Sure. So from index.cshtml...getting directed to index.js file...where the structure is :vue component(defined props, template...etc). New Vue element...created : function(){ axios.get(apiurl) .then (function(response){ ...some calculation....}...let me know if you need any other details. I am new to vuejs...learning along developing...

Comment: I see. So you're making the `axios.get(apiurl)` call in the mounting of your vue instance? Could you not move that elsewhere? What does that API call do?

Comment: I have not tried moving ….what do you suggest ? In Api call ...I have lots of charts to display... each have specific information like title, desc, apiurl...etc ...I am trying to loop it in html and then each and every chart is dynamically displayed....In my props I have ['title','apiurl']….fortunately...it is able to recognize title ..but the moment I add axios.get(apiurl)...I cannot get any chart displayed....

Comment: You likely need to use `this.apiurl`. Otherwise check in the Vue devtools that the `apiurl` prop is getting passed in correctly